# Is it better to store a physical Image into datastore or a link to it?

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence

I need to store images and I have 2 options:

- store the image into GAE datastore.
- store the image somewhere (maybe also on Dropbox or another website) and store its link into GAE datastore.

What's the best practice when we need to store an image into DB, in the hypotesis that each image is bijectivelly linked to a specific element of the datastore?

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends heavily on the use case.

I have a small company website running on appengine and the content images are all stored in the datastore and for that application it works well (they are all relatively small images).

If you have a high traffic site you may find storing them in GCS, or some other mechanism that supports a more cost effective CDN will be more appropriate.

If the images are large (more than 1MB) then the datastore isn't a practical solution.

There will be no hard and fast rule.  Understand your use cases, your cost structure, how complex the solution will be to manage, and then choose the most appropriate solution.

Comment: good point. I forgot to say that images are small (icon size)

Comment: GCS will likely cost a lot less than the datastore for image storage, and you can map domains to a bucket so you can keep all traffic within your domain.  In my case when an content image is uploaded I generate 4 images of different sizes from it,  uploading to GCS is a bit more complicated than writing each of these to the datastore.  Also you won't have unified logging, gcs logs go somewhere else. In my opinion a combined GCS (or other storage option -e.g. dropbox)/appengine environment will more than likely cost less, but will be a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the above. Google's cloud platform includes a service specifically for storing files, Google Cloud Storage, which is well integrated into GAE. You should use that.