# Datastore and Blobstore efficiency

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I want to display images with a description of the picture for each image on a website. What is the most efficient or best way to store the files on Google App Engine?

Store the text as string and picture as a blob in the database?

Or store the picture in Blobstore and a picture id or image key with the description in Datastore to link a connection between the two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to store a physical Image into datastore or a link to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712142/is-it-better-to-store-a-physical-image-into-datastore-or-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your image's in Google Cloud Storage and save all your metadatas in a ndb database. Google Cloud Storage is easy to use and similar of Blobstorage ([see the official doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage)) and with ndb database you can use free cotas of automatic memcaching system.